# Characters problem in Bit.ly

Tags: android, api, bit.ly

When I try to shorten a link with "#,&" character I get an exception. Is there a way to handle these character properly?

This is a sample code that works:

```
String shortUrl = bitly.getShortUrl("http://z"); //Works
```

If I add for example '&' or '%25' to the string it will throw an exception:

```
String shortUrl = bitly.getShortUrl("http://z%26"); // Exception 
String shortUrl = bitly.getShortUrl("http://z&"); // Exception
```

The `getShortUrl` function from [this Java class](http://github.com/finnjohnsen/BitlyAndroid/raw/master/src/com/finnjohnsen/bitlyandroid/test/BitlyAndroid.java).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library (the Java class you link to) doesn't escape the URL... that's pretty awful.

Excerpt:

```
private String getBitlyHttpResponseText(String urlToShorten) throws IOException {
  String uri = getBitlyUrl() + urlToShorten + bitlyAuth;
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
  ...
```

Notice how `urlToShorten` isn't escaped in any way, shape or form. Prone to injection-style attacks, and just generally doesn't work.

Anyway, you'll need to escape `urlToShorten`.